# How do i implement my ClassView to my template html for a search behavior?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I'm super new to django. I am trying to create a clone of pastebin.com which has only one model (Post) with name , content and generated_url.
I am having problem with the searchbar . I dont know how to implement the SearchView into search.html that generate

here's my model

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=300, blank=False)
    content = models.TextField()
    generated_url = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=10, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("pastebin_app:detail",kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

here's my root.html for the searchbar

```
<form action="{% url 'pastebin_app:search' %}" method="get" accept-charset="utf-8">

      <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search">

      <input type="submit" value="Search"/>

    </form>
```

and here's the views.py for searchview

```
class SearchView(ListView):
    template_name = 'pastebin_app/search.html'
    model = models.Post

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        q = request.GET.get('q', '')
        self.results = models.Post.objects.filter(name__icontains=q)
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return super().get_context_data(results=self.results, **kwargs)
```

Can someone please help me creating the show.html template that produce the search result from the SearchView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to checkout [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/) contains a simple api to help you get setup with filtering objects and also how to handle complex filters.

```
def product_list(request):
    f = ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=Product.objects.all())
    return render(request, 'my_app/template.html', {'filter': f})
```